# Enron classification - reading emails the wrong way

Tags: python, scikit-learn

currently i'm working a spam filter using sklearn, i'm wondering if i'm reading the dataaset in correctly? Using

```
#3 bag of words for ham, spam and both
#Explain fit_transform
bag_of_words = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(trainingData['data'].values)
ham_bag_of_words = ham_count_vectorizer.fit_transform(hamData['data'].values)
spam_bag_of_words = spam_count_vectorizer.fit_transform(spamData['data'].values)

sum_words = bag_of_words.sum(axis=0)
ham_sum_words = bag_of_words.sum(axis=0)
spam_sum_words = bag_of_words.sum(axis=0)

words_freq = [(word, sum_words[0, idx]) for word, idx in count_vectorizer.vocabulary_.items()]
ham_words_freq = [(word, ham_sum_words[0, idx]) for word, idx in ham_count_vectorizer.vocabulary_.items()]
spam_words_freq = [(word, spam_sum_words[0, idx]) for word, idx in spam_count_vectorizer.vocabulary_.items()]

words_freq = sorted(words_freq, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
ham_words_freq = sorted(ham_words_freq, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
spam_words_freq = sorted(spam_words_freq, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

#print(words_freq[:20])
#get top spam and ham phrases
print('SPAMS')
print(spam_words_freq[:20])
print('HAMS')
print(ham_words_freq[:20])`
```

I am getting the result:

```
 SPAMS
[('gtlwggzvs3cx9xjnhli2udpju7ftovfundhy09y3pn03zd36lij39j1krb1b', 359246), ('3dls077768', 343460), ('cdjprhbalvahdb', 323458), ('vnqrvtohzhaiwrb', 238241), ('p81vru', 185118), ('231314324245157275', 154698), ('ubmiy', 137509), ('wd7mk6g50', 129883), ('iyopb', 120343), ('zu2c9sjokfoixtzd4b1btdr0mwhs9rs7qak0jlxqzk7kaqgkgcjb4ry', 103636), ('gdzpai', 92823), ('cattani', 92092), ('dc9tzwrpys9uzxdzl3jlywquahrtbd9pbmrleg51bt01myzwywdlptema2v5y29kzt0ma2v5d29y', 89894), ('uzqmi6hlp6mbhg03bb3s3nn', 89575), ('unedr', 85048), ('ationary', 80743), ('iyhhoqgsw3akjfci90fbfzcsqtgzxrddygm1dfauasmdahm1adyoot', 76143), ('dbw5sv4rzwbp0bwww7wwrc', 70060), ('ivovf7mziw7hcxc', 69765), ('in_compliance', 67152)]
HAMS
[('instrum', 343460), ('creator', 154698), ('comptroller', 34111), ('isolatio', 33572), ('instrumen', 32503), ('intergen', 23028), ('mihura', 22310), ('ktora', 21611), ('anita', 20528), ('00', 19020), ('advertisement', 14892), ('anita_beilhart', 14741), ('09common', 12962), ('lane', 12585), ('lyst', 12385), ('creek', 11897), ('00000000', 10890), ('000', 10858), ('lipinski', 10636), ('cred', 10582)]
```

Not sure why the random strings are coming out. I expected typical spam words - buy, click, viagra ... etc?

Is count vectorizer transforming the data in some way? I'm surprised I don't see 'html' either.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you data coming from ?

Comment: This ended up being HTML represented a different way -